# Passing headers with axios POST request

Tags: axios, http-headers

I have written an Axios POST request as recommended from the npm package documentation like:

```js
var data = {
    'key1': 'val1',
    'key2': 'val2'
}
axios.post(Helper.getUserAPI(), data)       
.then((response) => {
    dispatch({type: FOUND_USER, data: response.data[0]})
})
.catch((error) => {
    dispatch({type: ERROR_FINDING_USER})
})
```

And it works, but now I have modified my backend API to accept headers.

> Content-Type: 'application/json'
>
> Authorization: 'JWT fefege...'

Now, this request works fine on Postman, but when writing an axios call, I follow **[this link](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios/issues/827)** and can't quite get it to work.

I am constantly getting `400 BAD Request` error.

Here is my modified request:

```js
axios.post(Helper.getUserAPI(), {
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'JWT fefege...'
    },
    data
})      
.then((response) => {
    dispatch({type: FOUND_USER, data: response.data[0]})
})
.catch((error) => {
    dispatch({type: ERROR_FINDING_USER})
})
```

Answer (score 573, accepted):

When using Axios, in order to pass custom headers, supply an object containing the headers as the last argument

Modify your Axios request like:

```js
const headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'Authorization': 'JWT fefege...'
}

axios.post(Helper.getUserAPI(), data, {
    headers: headers
  })
  .then((response) => {
    dispatch({
      type: FOUND_USER,
      data: response.data[0]
    })
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    dispatch({
      type: ERROR_FINDING_USER
    })
  })
```

Comment: @KishoreJethava, 500 is internal server error, can you check on server side if headers are coming or is there some other bug

Comment: @KishoreJethava, can you just log the headers in your server and see if you are getting the correct values

Comment: Dont you need to post any data? Also make sure this.state.token contains a value

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155236/discussion-between-kishore-jethava-and-shubham-khatri).

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri, may I ask you to have a look at an `axios` related question here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59470085/vue-js-validation-fails-for-file-upload-in-axios-when-multipart-form-data-used ?

Comment: What are these dispatch methods used for?

Comment: @DipanMandal dispatch is used to update the redux store from within actions. A redux-thunk middleware is involved in this syntax too

Comment: if i try this then my header is going as [object, object]. plz help!

Comment: This works for me, but I needed to base 64 encode my auth token with...  `const encodedAPIKey = Buffer.from(APIKey).toString('base64');` and I also prepended `Basic`

Comment: My issue was that I had Headers instead of headers. It is case sensitive, keep in mind.

Comment: Thanks for the example, took me a stupid amount of time to figure this out.

Comment: the answer which worked for 467 members is not helping for me.don't know what is the issue.i am also following the above answer in my application.but i am getting auth error.usually the auth error will come for me when header is not available.

Answer (score 75):

Here is a full example of an `axios.post` request with custom headers

```js
var postData = {
  email: "test@test.com",
  password: "password"
};

let axiosConfig = {
  headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
  }
};

axios.post('http://<host>:<port>/<path>', postData, axiosConfig)
.then((res) => {
  console.log("RESPONSE RECEIVED: ", res);
})
.catch((err) => {
  console.log("AXIOS ERROR: ", err);
})
```

Comment: facing this issue for get request. The response is coming in xml format. This doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: for that you need to add 

`headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8', "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*", "Accept": "application/json" }`

Please note this only works if your api supports json response

Comment: Why is this getting upvoted so much? `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is a **response** header and has no effect on request headers sent in JavaScript...

Answer (score 36):

To set headers in an Axios POST request, pass the third object to the `axios.post()` call.

```js
const token = '..your token..'

axios.post(url, {
  //...data
}, {
  headers: {
    'Authorization': `Basic ${token}` 
  }
})
```

To set headers in an Axios GET request, pass a second object to the `axios.get()` call.

```js
const token = '..your token..' 

axios.get(url, {
  headers: {
    'Authorization': `Basic ${token}`
  }
})
```

Answer (score 8):

```js
const data = {
  email: "me@me.com",
  username: "me"
};

const options = {
  headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  }
};

axios.post('http://path', data, options)
 .then((res) => {
   console.log("RESPONSE ==== : ", res);
 })
 .catch((err) => {
   console.log("ERROR: ====", err);
 })
```

All status codes above 400 will be caught in the Axios catch block.

Also, headers are optional for the post method in Axios

Answer (score 6):

You can also use interceptors to pass the headers

It can save you a lot of code

```js
axios.interceptors.request.use(config => {
  if (config.method === 'POST' || config.method === 'PATCH' || config.method === 'PUT')
    config.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json;charset=utf-8';

  const accessToken = AuthService.getAccessToken();
  if (accessToken) config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + accessToken;

  return config;
});
```

Comment: I would suggest to use `config.method.toUpperCase()`

Comment: Unfortunately, mine was lower

Answer (score 5):

We can pass headers as arguments,

```js
onClickHandler = () => {
  const data = new FormData();
  for (var x = 0; x < this.state.selectedFile.length; x++) {
    data.append("file", this.state.selectedFile[x]);
  }

  const options = {
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
  };

  axios
    .post("http://localhost:8000/upload", data, options, {
      onUploadProgress: (ProgressEvent) => {
        this.setState({
          loaded: (ProgressEvent.loaded / ProgressEvent.total) * 100,
        });
      },
    })
    .then((res) => {
      // then print response status
      console.log("upload success");
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      // then print response status
      console.log("upload fail with error: ", err);
    });
};
```

Answer (score 4):

[Shubham](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5928186/shubham-khatri)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44617848/11573842) didn't work for me.

When you are using the Axios library and to pass custom headers, you need to construct headers as an object with the key name 'headers'. The 'headers' key should contain an object, here it is `Content-Type` and `Authorization`.

The below example is working fine.

```js
var headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'JWT fefege...' 
}

axios.post(Helper.getUserAPI(), data, {"headers" : headers})
    .then((response) => {
        dispatch({type: FOUND_USER, data: response.data[0]})
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        dispatch({type: ERROR_FINDING_USER})
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

`axios.post` can accept 3 arguments that the last argument can accept a `config` object that you can set header.

Sample code with your question:

```js
var data = {
'key1': 'val1',
'key2': 'val2'
}
axios.post(Helper.getUserAPI(), data, {
        headers: {Authorization: token && `Bearer ${ token }`}
})       
.then((response) => {
    dispatch({type: FOUND_USER, data: response.data[0]})
})
.catch((error) => {
    dispatch({type: ERROR_FINDING_USER})
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using some property from vuejs prototype that can't be read on creation you can also define headers and write i.e.

```js
storePropertyMaxSpeed(){
  axios
    .post(
      "api/property",
      {
        property_name: "max_speed",
        property_amount: this.newPropertyMaxSpeed,
      },
      {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          Authorization: "Bearer " + this.$gate.token(),
        },
      }
    )
    .then(() => {
      //this below peace of code isn't important
      Event.$emit("dbPropertyChanged");

      $("#addPropertyMaxSpeedModal").modal("hide");

      Swal.fire({
        position: "center",
        type: "success",
        title: "Nova brzina unešena u bazu",
        showConfirmButton: false,
        timer: 1500,
      });
    })
    .catch(() => {
      Swal.fire("Neuspješno!", "Nešto je pošlo do đavola", "warning");
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

**Interceptors**

I had the same issue and the reason was that I hadn't returned the response in the interceptor. Javascript thought, rightfully so, that I wanted to return `undefined` for the promise:

```js
// Add a request interceptor
axios.interceptors.request.use(function (config) {
    // Do something before request is sent
    return config;
  }, function (error) {
    // Do something with request error
    return Promise.reject(error);
  });
```