# Reactjs POST request through axios

Tags: javascript, java, reactjs, axios

Hi i am trying reactjs POST request through axios but getting error, I went through all docs but error is not solved.

Here is my error:

Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 400
    at createError (eval at  (bundle.js:4621), :15:15)
    at settle (eval at  (bundle.js:4615), :18:12)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (eval at  (bundle.js:4609), :77:7)

Here is my Reactjs code:

```
import React from 'react';
import RaisedButton from 'material-ui/RaisedButton';
import TextField from 'material-ui/TextField';
import axios from 'axios';
const style = {
 margin: 15,
marginLeft: 600
};
export default class  Register extends React.Component {
 constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.onSubmit=this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
}


handleSubmit(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   var self = this;
   var data = new FormData();
   const payload = {
   id: 111,
   studentName: 'param',
   age: 24,
   emailId: 2
};
data.append("myjsonkey", JSON.stringify(payload));

axios('http://localhost:8083/students',{
   method: 'POST',
   body: data,
   headers: {
    // 'Authorization': `bearer ${token}`,
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }
 })
   .then(function(response) {
       return response.json()
     }).then(function(body) {
       console.log(body);
     });
 }

render() {
   return (
     <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
     <div style={style}>
     <TextField ref='id'
     hintText="Enter Student id"
     floatingLabelText="id"
     />
     <br/>
     <TextField ref='sname'
     hintText="Enter your Last Name"
     floatingLabelText="StudentName"
     />
     <br/>
     <TextField ref='age'
     hintText="Enter your Age"
     floatingLabelText="age"
     />
     <br/>

     <TextField ref='emailId'
     hintText="Enter your Email"
     floatingLabelText="emailId"
     />
     <br/>
     <br/>
     <input type="submit" />


     </div>
         </form>


   );
 }


}
```

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44617825/passing-headers-with-axios-post-request-reactjs/44617848#44617848, Also in your implementation data is send with `body` whereas it should be sent as `data`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Checking [axios api](https://github.com/axios/axios#axios-api) the correct way of making POST request is:

```
const payload = {
  id: 111,
  studentName: 'param',
  age: 24,
  emailId: 2
}

axios({
  method: 'post',
  url: '/user/12345',
  data: payload, // you are sending body instead
  headers: {
   // 'Authorization': `bearer ${token}`,
  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }, 
})
```

Comment: @SpRaju remove the `FormData` and `JSON.stringify ` implementations. You can POST data as a JavaScript object. I updated my answer as well :)

Answer (score 1):

There is no need of sending form data

```
var data = new FormData();
```

Just pass json to via axios ,

```
axios('http://localhost:8083/students',{
   method: 'POST',
   data : payload,
   headers: {
    // 'Authorization': `bearer ${token}`,
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }
})
```

Simple way to do :

```
axios.post('http://localhost:8083/students',payload).then(...)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  var authOptions = {
     method: 'post',
     url: 'https://exam.com/apps',
     data: JSON.stringify({"name": "ddd"});,
     headers: {
       'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
     json: true
    };
 axios(authOptions)
    .then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
        })
    .catch((error) => {
       alert(error)
      })
```

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the bellow steps to resolve

First define the constructor

```
 constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
                id: ,
       studentName: '',
               age: ,
           emailId: '',
        };
```

write the **handleSubmit** Method

```
handleSubmit (evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    console.log("Submit");
    const payload = {
                 id : this.state.id,
        studentName : this.state.studentName,
                age : this.state.age,
            emailId : this.state.emailId,  
    }

    axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: 'url-url',
        data: payload, 

    }).then(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    }).catch(function (error){
        console.log(error);});
}
```

please don't forget bind the **handleSubmit** method

```
this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
```

This will solved the problem