# auth token is not assigned to headers in axios

Tags: reactjs, axios, mern

[image]Getting this error:

[image]

```
     await axios
      .post("http://localhost:5000/books/addBook",
      {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
         "auth-token": localStorage.getItem('token'),
        },
       body:({
        name: String(inputs.name),
        author: String(inputs.author),
        description: String(inputs.description),
        price: Number(inputs.price),
        image: String(inputs.image),
        available: Boolean(checked),
      })
     })
      .then((res) => res.data);
```

this is code token has been there but not assigned to headers

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing headers with axios POST request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44617825/passing-headers-with-axios-post-request)

Comment: Can we have the Request header in the network tab?

Comment: Is your backend accepting `auth-token` header?

Comment: @underscore yess

Comment: no whenever i send request then the headers are gone in data not as headers

Answer (score 2):

The second parameter in `post` is the data that you need to send to the api and then you set the headers in the `config param`  so in order to send the data and the headers properly you have to do this:

> axios.post(url[, data[, config]])

```
await axios
      .post("http://localhost:5000/books/addBook",{
        name: String(inputs.name),
        author: String(inputs.author),
        description: String(inputs.description),
        price: Number(inputs.price),
        image: String(inputs.image),
        available: Boolean(checked),
      },
      {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
         "auth-token": localStorage.getItem('token'),
        },
     })
      .then((res) => res.data);
```