# cakephp XMLHttpRequest post request csrf problem

Tags: cakephp, axios, http-post, csrf, cakephp-4.x

cakephp 4.4.6

I use vuejs as frontend, all works fine, but I have csrf problems to send XMLHttpRequest with post request.
CsrfProtectionMiddleware is activated.

It works fine when post data are send from an html "form" (_csrfToken is in a hidden field).

But if post data are send from an axios request, cakephp backend cannot get the csrf token.

Here is the front code:

```
axios
            .post("/equipes/delete", {
                headers: {
                    "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
                    'X-CSRF-Token': this.csrftoken,
                },
                params: {
                    // csrfToken: this.csrftoken,
                    // _csrfToken: this.csrftoken,
                    id: id,
                },
            })
            .then((response) => {
                
            })
            .catch((e) => {
                console.log(this.$options.name + ": method confirmationDelete : error");
            });
```

The parameters send to the cakephp backend:
[image]

And the error returned :

[image]

Any ideas ?
Thanks

Comment: **https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44617825/passing-headers-with-axios-post-request**

Comment: Thanks @ndm, it works fine (axios post parameters were not correct)